# Enclosing strings with forward slashes using AWK

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I have a php file in which split() function was used extensively. I replaced it to preg_split using sed and find commands. The problem now is preg_split requires the regex pattern to be enclosed in delimiters while split does not require it.

I have tried using SED to enclose the strings with delimiters but SED is unable to it according to my knowledge. I have come to know that AWK kan solve this problem.

I want

```
 preg_split('\r\n', $some_string);
```

to be modified as

```
 preg_split('/\r\n/', $some_string);
```

where the forward slashes work as delimiters. How can this be done using AWK?

Comment: The point of the two (original) answers, which they both fail to mention, is that `sed` does not have to use `/` as its delimiter. In triplee's answer colon `:` is being used as the delimiter; in damgad's answer it is `#` that is the delimiter.  This makes it easy to use forward-slashes in both patterns and replacements with sed.

Comment: @Ashkan: That was a typo, updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is perfectly capable of this.

```
sed "s:\(preg_split('\)\(([^']*\)':\1/\2/':g" file.php
```

Your `sed` dialect might want a different mix of backslashes; or use Perl (or, ugh, PHP);

```
perl -pi~ -e "s:(preg_split\(')([^']*)':$1/$2/':g" file.php
```

(Notice the `-i` flag for in-place editing; perhaps your `sed` supports that, too?)

I'm imagining your problem was with quoting rather than with the actual `sed` regex. Getting single quotes properly quoted in the shell can be a challenge. (In the worst case, put your shell script in a file so the shell won't see it.) And of course, using a different delimiter instead of slash makes the expression simpler.

Answer (score 1):

That should work as you expect:

```
 sed "s#preg_split('\(.*\)'#preg_split('/\1/'#g"
```

As @Stephen P mentioned in comment. You can use different delimeters with sed. If your delimiter is used in regex or replacement string you have to escape it using `\`. It's always simplier to use the delimiter which does not exist in your regex and replacement string. Here, I used `#`.

Comment: The greedy wildcard will match too much if there are other single-quoted strings on the same line. The trivial fix is to use `[^']*` instead of `.*`.

Comment: @tripleee Isn't using a `'` in single quoted string allowed in php? In `preg_split('\r\n\'sth', $some_string);` the `.*` will match corretly and `[^']*` will fail. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's either/or, or a much more complex regex.